# Onto continuous between two space

Tags: general-topology

suppose that

$$X=(\{0\}\times [-2,2])\cup([0,2]\times \{0\})$$

$$Y=(\{0\}\times [-2,2])\cup([0,2]\times \{-1,1\})$$

Is there any onto continuous function from $X$ to $Y$?

Is there any onto continuous function from $Y$ to $X$?

when draw $X$ it looks like latter T and draw $Y$ almost latter T. 
and both $X$ and $Y$ are connected and compact. However, I can not complete it even thought I attempted many times.
Any help will be appreciated.

why this problem makes challenge to one whose knowledge about topology is not strong enough.

Comment: Do you mean $\times$ rather than $*$? And please correct your grammar/punctuation errors.

Comment: Yes. I mean $\times $rather than *

Answer (score 1):

To map $Y$ onto $X$ let $f(x,y)=(x,y)$ if $y<0, $ and $f(x,y)=(x,-y)$ if $y\geq 0.$ Let $g(x,y)=(x,2y+2).$ Then $h=gf$ maps $Y$ onto $X.$

Notation: $f''A=f''(A)=\{f(x): x\in A\}$ when $A\subset$ dom$(f).$

To map $X$ onto $Y$  it is easier (for me) to describe a map $f:[0,7]\to Y$ and to let $h=gf$ where $g:X\to [0,7]$ is a continuous surjection.

Let $f''[0,1]=\{0\}\times [-2,-1]$ with $f(1)=(0,-1).$

Let $f''[1,2]=[0,2]\times \{-1\}$ with $f(2)=(2,-1).$

Let $f''[2,3]=[0,2]\times \{-1\}$ with $f(3)=(0,-1).$

Let $f''[3,4]=\{0\}\times [-1,1]$ with $f(4)=(0,1).$

Let $f''[4,5]=[0,2]\times \{1\}$ with $f(5)=(2,1).$

Let $f''[5,6]=[0,2]\times \{1\}$ with $f(6)=(0,1).$

Let $f''[6,7]=\{0\}\times [1,2].$

Comment: Thank you for writing back. I have question because I say this kind of construction for continuous function first time . If there are some facts which help you to come up with this idea .My background of topology just the first six chapters of Munkers's

Comment: I pictured a bug $b$ travelling along $[0,7]$ and a corresponding $f(b)$ on $Y$ and got the idea for  $b\in [0,3],$  and the rest was obvious.Before that, I wasted 10 minutes trying to show it was impossible. It IS impossible to get a continuous bijection, though, because a continuous bijection between compact Hausdorff spaces is a homeomorphism, and $X,Y$ are not homeomorphic: Each of the "end-points" has a local base $B$ such that the set $\bar b$ \ $b$ has just one member.  $X$ has exactly 3 points with this property but  $Y$ has 4.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: For the $Y\to X$ map: First, find a continuous $g:[-2,2] \to X$ that is onto. Then define $f:Y \to X$ by setting $f(x,y) = g(y).$ The idea for the $X\to Y$ map is similar.

Comment: Could you explain how the function $g$ define becuse I am not familiar with Peano Curve

Comment: Then it's time to look it up. The internet is a wonderful thing.

Comment: Other any suggestions rather than Use Peano. Space because it is not in my lectures. So, there is another method. Any one his idea

Comment: My apologies to you. I thought $[0,2]\times \{-1,1\}$ was $[0,2]\times  [-1,1].$  I'll delete the answer for now and rethink.

Comment: I edited my answer.

Comment: Just I read about Peano space from internet if both spaces are Peano space or not

Comment: It's good to know about Peano, but in this problem it's not useful.